# Create and increment file name if the name exists

Tags: java, file

I have a file that stores Test questions.

```
"Test.ser"
```

I want to be able to create files with the same name but with some incrementor appended for each time someone takes the Test to store the Answers.

```
"Test1.ser"
"Test2.ser"
   ...
```

However, I can't think of a way to implement this. A counter could work, but the counter would reset if someone re-ran the program.

Does anyone have an idea how this is possible? Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

```
int count = 1;
while (searching) {
    fileName = survey.name + Integer.toString(count) + ".ser";
    f = new File(fileName);

    if(f.exists()) {
        count++;
    } else {
        searching = false;
    }
} // Proceed to use file name
```

Can't get it it increment past file_name1.ser

Comment: Just keep incrementing the counter and trying filenames until the file name does not exist.

Comment: @JasonC Thanks Jason, I didn't think of that. I will try using this method!

Comment: Class File has a method exists(). Just create a sequence of filenames until you find an unused one.

Comment: Trying to use your strategy, however having issues. I posted an edit.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you use [`String.format(String, Object...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), [`File.exists()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) and something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String fmt = "Test%02d.ser";
    File f = null;
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++) {
        f = new File(String.format(fmt, i));
        if (!f.exists()) {
            break;
        }
    }
    try {
        System.out.println(f.getCanonicalPath());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**Edit**

As pointed out in the comments, this only retries 100 times. If you want to support more then 100 retries you could write the `for` loop like,

```
for (int i = 1;; i++)
```

Comment: This will throw an NPE if 100 files exist. Probably not desirable behavior.

Comment: @JasonC I decided it should fail fast if you fail the test 100 times, I don't think a 101st is going to help.

Comment: What I mean is it should probably fail with something more informative than an NPE. ("Not desirable" referred to throwing the NPE, not to failing after 100 files, sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to solve this would be appending the date and the time to your filename.

For example using the format (YYYYMMDD-HHMM):

```
Test-20141122_2058.ser
Test-20141123_1931.ser
Test-20141123_2157.ser
```

Comment: Adding to this: Consider adding seconds, or a random string on the end (or even e.g. the process or thread ID), if multiple users can take this test at once or if the test can take under 60 seconds to complete.

Comment: This way is good to create file but it is not practical when the file are read.

Comment: Why not? You could fetch the names with a regular expression, that is quite fast.
Perhaps I should add an answersId before the date and time and you could read the files easily by answersId.