# How to dynamically rename csv exports, when using csv writer in Java

Tags: java

I have the below code which exports a Jtable as Excel csv export.

I tried appending the file (boolean true), but the append happens within the same file itself.

```
public static boolean exportToCSV(JTable table,String pathToExportTo) {

try {

    TableModel model = table.getModel();            
    FileWriter csv = new FileWriter(new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.csv"));

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getColumnCount(); i++) {
        csv.write(model.getColumnName(i) + ",");
    }

    csv.write("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < model.getRowCount(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < model.getColumnCount(); j++) {
            csv.write(model.getValueAt(i, j).toString() + ",");
        }
        csv.write("\n");
    }

    csv.close();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Export Successful!");
    return true;

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error! Excel cannot be exported!");
}
return false;
```

This is working fine, but this overwrites the existing file. I would want this to be exported as a different file and probably rename as text(1).csv

Comment: So change the name of the file: `FileWriter csv = new FileWriter(new File("C:/Users/user/Desktop/test (1).csv"));`

Comment: Thans Andy, but is there a way to do this dynamically, like the first export will be named as "test.csv", every other consecutive export as "test(1).csv" , "test(2).csv" etc

Comment: Sure, make a method that figures it out, then call it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create and increment file name if the name exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27096374/create-and-increment-file-name-if-the-name-exists)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a method to compute report output file:

```
File resolveFileName(){
    String directory ="C:/Users/user/Desktop/";

    File res = new File(directory + "test.csv");
    if(!res.exists()){
        return res;
    }
    int filesInDirectoryCount = (new File(directory)).listFiles().length;
    String fileName = "test_"+filesInDirectoryCount+".csv";
    return new File(directory+fileName);
}
```

Usage:

```
FileWriter csv = new FileWriter(resolveFileName);
```

This will add a numer to the file name, based on numer of files in this directory. So it should help with this problem.